# Nginx - Angular Universal + Simple Angular Configuration

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a server, on which two different projects - user(Angular Universal) and admin(Simple Angular) will be deployed.

User project is developed using Angular universal. For user project I have following nginx configurations - which is working good.

**nginx.conf** (minimum content)

```
# Running on Node
upstream nrc_frontend_nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
...

root /home/user/webapp/dist;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri @backend; # <--- This looks for requests (statics)
                                      # in dist folder. If nothing found, calls @backend
    }

    location @backend {

        proxy_pass http://nrc_frontend_nodejs;
        .... Own server configurations
    }
```

User project is working good.

Now I am trying to add another simple angular project (admin project - without universal - technically static content). So I created a folder "admin" inside /home/user/webapp/

Then I have tried multiple ways to make it work, but its not working. Mostly it redirects to user project.

**nginx.conf** (lines added before `location /`)

```
  location /admin {
        root /home/user/webapp/admin;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; #<--- because its angular project
   }
```

So now when I hit *site.com/admin* or *site.com/admin/blah/blah* it always redirects to user project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you are trying to access two angular projects using different URL's.

One of them which is Angular Universal is working correctly by proxying it.

Now you want to add a Normal Angular dist under different URL.

So i would suggest to use another server block inside the nginx configuration file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/user/webapp/admin;


    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This should work perfectly. Let me know if you have any trouble or i understood the whole problem differently.